# DataTemplate binding in ancestor mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Suppose we have the following code:

**MyGridViewColumn.xaml**

```
<GridViewColumn x:Class="some_namespace.MyGridViewColumn"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}}, Path=MyString, Mode=OneTime"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

**MyGridViewColumn.xaml.cs**

```
namespace some_namespace
{
    public partial class MyGridViewColumn
    {
        public MyGridViewColumn()
        {
            MyString = "Hello!";
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string MyString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This feels ok, but it doesn't work. What is the correct binding to "MyString"?

Comment: x:Class can only be specified for the root element.  Doesn't make sense to set GridViewColumn as root element, not sure if this is even possible.  Does your code compile?  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189082(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Yes, the code compiles, but "MyString" cannot be accessed through this binding: "Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}}, Path=MyString, Mode=OneTime". Moreover, "GridViewColumn" is indeed the root element, so it's correct until now. If a make it a user control for instance, it will work, but without user control as root element, it seems to not...

Comment: In this case I think you can get away with just changing the part `Path=MyString` to `Path=DataContext.MyString` to hit your parents